# How to toggle the visibility of the PROPERTIES drawer programmatically?

Tags: org-mode

## Prologue

I heavily use the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer. Because of this, I want to create a function that would allow me to toggle the visibility of the `:PROPERTIES:` of the current subtree. I want the function to also work at the top level of the document (recall that a `:PROPERTIES:` drawer can be used in the top level of the document to set a property for all the subtrees in the current document).

I could use `org-cycle`, but in order to use this function, I need the cursor to be on the drawer, and I want the function to work regardless of the position of the cursor.

## The question

1. Is there any native function that accomplishes this behavior?
2. If that's not the case, what functions could I use to accomplish this desired behavior?

Comment: Doesn't `TAB` (bound to `org-cycle`) work?

Comment: Yes, but to use `org-cycle`, you need to make sure that the cursor is on the drawer, and I was wondering how to do this regardless of the position of the cursor. I've edited the question so that that is explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a native function for doing that, but you can define your custom function.

```
(defun my/org-toggle-properties-drawer-current-subtree ()
  "Toggles the visibility of the PROPERTIES drawer of the current subtree."
  (interactive)
  (cond
   ;; If the cursor is on the top level of the document
   ((null (org-current-level))
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-buffer)
      (unless (org-at-property-drawer-p)
        (error "The top level of the document doesn't have a PROPERTIES drawer."))
      (org-hide-drawer-toggle)))
   ;; If the cursor is on a headline
   ((eq (car (org-element-at-point)) 'headline)
    (save-excursion
      (next-line)
      (unless (org-at-property-drawer-p)
        (error "This heading doesn't have a PROPERTIES drawer."))
      (org-hide-drawer-toggle)))
   ;; If the cursor is not on a headline and is not in the top level
   ;; of the document, then it is inside a subtree.
   (t (save-excursion
        (org-previous-visible-heading 1)
        (next-line)
        (unless (org-at-property-drawer-p)
          (error "This heading doesn't have a PROPERTIES drawer."))
        (org-hide-drawer-toggle)))))
```

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c t p") 'my/org-toggle-properties-drawer-current-subtree)
```

Comment: I have not run your function, I've just read the code, but I think there are a couple of potential problems: 1) there may be scheduling information between a headline and a property drawer, so `(next-line)` is probably not enough: you have to search for the drawer  - that applies to both the second and the third case of the cond; 2)  in the subtree case,  did you only want to go to the previous visible heading or to the previous visible heading *with* a property drawer?